# passing an array in intent android

Tags: android, arrays, android-intent, bundle

So I've always been under the assumption that you can't pass arrays between activities with extras. But I was just going through the Bundle class docs and saw `putStringArray(String key, String[] value)` and `public String[] getStringArray (String key)`. Are these new? They both say since API lvl 1, but I don't remember being able to pass arrays. Am I going crazy here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you must be able to pass string[] as a bundle in Android. Any specific reason you have for getting into such a conclusion?

Refer to this post

http://www.anddev.org/view-layout-resource-problems-f27/how-can-i-pass-multidimensional-string-array-two-activities-t9259.html

Comment: I think I'm just going crazy. I was sure I'd looked into passing an array, tried it, failed, and asked on SO about it and was told it can't be done. I think I need some sleep, lol

Answer (score 0):

You can pass any `Serializable` object as extra, so I don't see why you could not pass `String` array. There is a `setExtra(String, Serializable)` method in the `Intent`, that's what I use.