# List view row pressed

Tags: java, android

I have a list view with couple of items and i set this function get call when a row in the list view is clicked.

I want to open new activity and send him an object from an array of objects.
I have a problem with this line :

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, Item_Activity.class);
```

because the `this` is now no the activity.

this is the code:

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
         public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
             Intent i = new Intent(this, Item_Activity.class);
             Item item = m_items.get(position);
             i.putExtra("object", item);
             startActivity(i);
         }

    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem:**

You are passing the wrong context in

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, Item_Activity.class);
```

**Solution:**

Use : `YourActivityName.this` instead if using simply `this`

eg.  `Intent i = new Intent(CurrentActivityName.this, Item_Activity.class);`

Answer (score 1):

Add ActivityName.this instead of this only,

Intent i = new Intent(ActivityName.this, Item_Activity.class);

Answer (score 0):

is your Item is parcelable, if not make this object parcelable by following link:
http://prasanta-paul.blogspot.in/2010/06/android-parcelable-example.html

Answer (score 0):

Your object has to be either serializable or parcelable and I don't think you can pass
an array into an intent read this - [How to pass an object from one activity to another on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2736389/how-to-pass-object-from-one-activity-to-another-in-android)

more to that

[passing an array in intent android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3597974/passing-an-array-in-intent-android)