# Reading String[] in another activity for SimpleAdapter

Tags: android, string, arrays

I have a method called getData() in an Activity that returns a String[]:

Example:

```
public class Strings{
    public String[] getData(){
    String[] data = {"one","two","three"};
    return data;
    }
}
```

My question is how to retrieve these items, because in another activity I want to put this into a SimpleAdapter list.  I can call

```
String[] data = Strings.getData();
```

then have that as a variable that is technically the array, but I need to read out the items into the adapter.  I know its probably simple but like I said, noob, haha.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6355787/how-to-pass-arraylist-from-one-activity-to-another and herehttp://stackoverflow.com/questions/3597974/passing-an-array-in-intent-android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For sharing data between different activity, I think you need to send that data with Intent before you change Activity

```
intent.putExtra("TheStrings", this.getStrings());
```